# convert txt file into Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark

How can I read txt file into `Dataset<Row>` without using `JavaRDD<MyObject>`? Not able to use `Encoder` for `Row` type.

Data.txt

```
ID,Name,Salary
1,A,100
2,B,200
3,C,300
4,D,400
5,E,500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use csv() method available on DataFrameReader class.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("file.txt");
ds.show();
/*
+---+----+------+
| ID|Name|Salary|
+---+----+------+
|  1|   A|   100|
|  2|   B|   200|
|  3|   C|   300|
|  4|   D|   400|
|  5|   E|   500|
+---+----+------+ */
```

Comment: just did the same thing :)